# Ubuntu 22.04 - Why when I launch Ubuntu Software, the Snap Store launches now?

Tags: software-center, snap

Just after a fresh installation, every time I launched Ubuntu Software the orange icon will be active. Recently I installed two apps from the web, Cisco Webex and the Edge browser, I download the .deb files, and installed them using Software Install.

Since then, now every time I launch Ubuntu Software, the Snap Store app icon will launch. Also, If I search for Snap Store, it will not find it, as an available app to run.

Please any help clarifying the situation will be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The name of a package (`snap-store`)
The name of an application at a shell prompt (`snap-store`)
The name of an application in the GUI (`Ubuntu Software`)

These are three names for the same software, and all three are provided by the same package. One or more names might change with a new release of Ubuntu.